# vertically moving javascript button or menu on uiwebview

Tags: javascript, iphone, uiwebview, iphone-sdk-3.1

I am facing lots of problems in handling the touch event of the uiwebview for making my tabbar and navigation bar hides/unhide. I thought of putting a horizontally moving button or a small text on the uiwebview which will move along with the user scrolling.

If the user touches the button which moves along with the user scroll i am planning to show or hide the nav and tab bar. Is this possible in uiwebview ? if yes please give me an idea or bunch of code snippets for writing such a menu using javascript

Answer (score 0):

You may need a UIView that contains the UIWebView, along with other controls you mentioned, e.g. buttons. You may make the button semi-transparent and receive touch events.